# sequelize Как выполнить create для массива с проверкой на дубликаты?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Приходит массив объектов. Один объект - одна запись в таблицу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в sequealize реализация добавления массива, а также проверка на дубликаты? Или надо вручную проходится по массиву, выполнять проверку и если что записывать?

Например, есть таблица `table` с полем `name`. С тремя записями string1, string2, string3.
И есть массив

```
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'string4', 
  },
  {
    name: 'string2',
  },
  {
    name: 'string5',
  },
];
```

Нужно добавить этот массив в таблицу так, чтобы теперь у нас были там строки string1, string2, string3, string4, sytring5. Без повторяющейся string2.

Comment: Какая СУБД? Версия?

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от СУБД и того есть ли уникальный индекс на поле `name`, то можно пользоваться функцией `upsert`, передав ей этот массив объектов.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'string4', 
  },
  {
    name: 'string2',
  },
  {
    name: 'string5',
  },
];
await TableModeol.upsert(arr);
```

Comment: А чем отличается upsert от bulkCreate? Потому что у меня вроде удалось сделать с помощью indexes и unique в модели в комбинации с bulkCreate для добавления новых данных

Comment: upsert может обновлять существующие, а bulkCreate только добавляет

Comment: Спасибо @Anatoly

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить таким образом:
Для модели добавил свойство `indexes`, в котором указал необходимые поля и `unique: true`, типа такого:

```
indexes: [
  {
     unique: true,
     fields: ['userId', 'roleId'],
   }
 ],
```

А для самого запроса использовал `bulkCreate` `ignoreDuplicates: true`, типа

```
const roles = body.roles.map((role) => ({ userId: params.id, roleId: role }));
await this.UserRole.bulkCreate(roles, {
  ignoreDuplicates: true,
});
```

В итоге, в таблицу заносится все как надо, но если что обратите внимание на то, как выглядят данные, которые были дубликатами в результате выполнения запроса. Присвойте результат `bulkCreate` какой-нибудь переменной `test`, передайте данные которые уже есть в таблице и изучить `console.log(test);`